# Nginx Laravel and phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure a Laravel application, along with phpmyadmin. The default / should redirect to the laravel application, while /phpmyadmin should point to phpmyadmin. The following is my nginx config file:

```
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;

server_name example.com;

root /var/www/html/laravel/public;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location /phpmyadmin {
    alias /var/www/html/phpmyadmin;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

I have tried several other configuration but none of them worked, the current one works on the laravel redirection, but when navigating to /phpmyadmin it always return a 404.